# How do I update product price in Stripe using PHP API?

Tags: stripe-payments, price

Now I'm working on Stripe where I could set price for the product using PHP API call, but unable to update price amount. How can I do that?

My used code:

```
$price = $this->stripe->prices->update('price_1LRwQ6HEtJIPaXSgzQFrZtv7', [
    'unit_amount' => $request->unit_amount * 100,            
]);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like updating unit_amount on a price is supported. You'd likely want to create a new price and update the default_price [1] on the Product.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/update?lang=php#update_product-default_price

Answer (score 2):

I already solved the issue. In Stripe, a price update is not possible directly, just do the following to make it happen:

1. Delete the existing price.
2. Create new price for the product.

```
$this->stripe->plans->delete(
    $price_data['stripe_price_id'],
    []
);
$price = $this->stripe->prices->create([
    'unit_amount' => $request->price * 100,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'recurring' => ['interval' => 'month'],
    'product' => $data['stripe_product_id'],
]);
```

Comment: It's really weird that updating the price doesn't seem to work, since they have an `update` api.